# Select periods of validity of the historical table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a job where I have to select records in the periods which were active

My sample of the initial data is:

```
 department_id,  employee_id,  start_dt,     end_dt
       1            11         2016-01-01    2016-01-03
       1            11         2016-01-04    2016-01-07
       1            11         2016-01-08    2016-01-11
       1            12         2016-01-12    2016-01-14
       1            12         2016-01-15    2016-01-17
       1            12         2016-01-18    2016-01-20
       1            11         2016-01-21    2016-01-24
       1            11         2016-01-25    2016-01-25
       1            14         2016-01-26    2016-01-27
       2            11         2016-04-01    2016-04-10
```

My expected output:

```
 department_id,  employee_id,  start_dt,     end_dt
       1            11         2016-01-01    2016-01-11
       1            12         2016-01-12    2016-01-20
       1            11         2016-01-21    2016-01-25
       1            14         2016-01-26    2016-01-27
       2            11         2016-04-01    2016-04-10
```

I tried with `max/min and partition by` but `employee_id` may repeat in one `department_id` at various times

Comment: It's possible you can cast this problem as a search for *inactive* times.

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using [**LAG**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) analytic function, the problem is commonly called as *Groups and Island problem*

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT department_id, 
                employee_id, 
                start_dt, 
                end_dt, 
                Sum(CASE WHEN pstart = employee_id THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
                  OVER(partition BY department_id ORDER BY start_dt) AS Counter 
         FROM   (SELECT department_id, 
                        employee_id, 
                        start_dt, 
                        end_dt, 
                        Lag(employee_id, 1, NULL) OVER( partition BY department_id 
                            ORDER BY start_dt) AS pstart 
                 FROM   #Table1 ) t) 
SELECT department_id, 
       employee_id, 
       min(start_dt) as start_dt, 
       max(end_dt) as  end_dt
FROM   (SELECT row_number() OVER(partition BY department_id, counter 
                   ORDER BY start_dt) AS rn, 
               department_id, employee_id, start_dt, end_dt ,counter
        FROM   cte) a 
group by department_id,
         employee_id,
         counter
```

Comment: You can check me for department 11 and the first occurrence of it gets results: start='2016-01-01'    end='2016-01-03' and I should start='2016-01-01' end=' 2016-01-11'

Comment: @AdamNowak - yeah, fixed it check now

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain the periods of activity together.  One method is to determine when a period starts -- and create a flag for this.  A cumulative sum then identifies a group of activity.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
select department_id, employee_id, min(start_dt) as start_dt,
       max(end_dt) as end_t
from (select t.*,
             sum(IsGroupStart) over (partition by department_id, employee_id order by start_dt) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when exists (select 1
                                      from t t2
                                      where t2.department_id = t.department_id and  
                                            t2.employee_id = t.employee_id and
                                            t.start_dt between t2.start_dt and t2.end_dt + 1
                                     )
                         then 0 else 1
                    end) as IsGroupStart
employee_id
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by department_id, employee_id, grp;
```

Comment: In this case,  for the first the department gets only 3 summary of erroneous dates and should 4 as in the example

Comment: @AdamNowak . . . I see the problem.  I left out the `order by` clause is in the `sum()` so it was not doing a cumulative sum to generate the `grp` value.